# difference between XmlSerializerOutputFormatter and XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, output-formatting

I am wondering what is the difference between these two serializers. when setting accept header = application/xml. Am using Plain DTOs as return values, Which one is preferred? Also consumer of the api who request xml in response which should be used?

Am working on aspnet core web api 3.1, building restful apis. Any suggestions/redirects on the above query will be helpful.

Comment: The XmSerializer starts at root of xml files and deserializes everything.  The DataContract you specify the tag of the contract in the properties and you get only the contract tag name and children.

Comment: @jdweng In case of DTOs does this makes a diifference when response is serialised?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I haven't look at the xml responses in a sniffer to give an answer.  A HTML response has a header and a body and I "thought" the xml response is contained in the body of the response.  The Xml Serializer responses I've seen usually have the header and body while the Data Contract responses the removes the header and body and tunnels down to the contract tag name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter` is an asp.net core  outputformatter that uses the `XmlSerializer` internally, whereas the `DataContractSerializerOutputFormatter` uses the `DataContractSerializer` internally.

The `DataContractSerializer` is more flexible in configuration. For example it supports reference detection to prevent the serializer from recursively serializing items, which would normally cause an endless loop.

In my own projects, I prefer to use the `DataContractSerializerOutputFormatter` because it's able to cope with properties with private setter

```
public string Text { get; private set; }
```

### Failing case

#### Dtos project

```
namespace DataContractSerializerPOC.Dtos
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        // Fullname can only be set from this project
        public string FullName { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class PersonService
    {
        public List<Person> GetPeople()
        {
            // Create a list of people to be serialized
            var people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
                new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Flix" },
                new Person { Id = 3, FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Splick" },
            };
            
            // Set the fullname from this project
            // In some cases you may need to do this, instead of implementing a readonly property
            foreach (var person in people)
                person.FullName = $"{person.FirstName} {person.LastName}";

            return people;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Console project

```
namespace DataContractSerializerPOC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var personService = new PersonService();
            var people = personService.GetPeople();

            var writer = new StringWriter();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, people);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image: Cannot deserialize type because it contains property which has no public setter]

### Working case with DataContractSerializer

#### Dtos project

```
namespace DataContractSerializerPOC.Dtos
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        // Fullname can only be set from this project
        [DataMember]
        public string FullName { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class PersonService
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Console project

```
namespace DataContractSerializerPOC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var personService = new PersonService();
            var people = personService.GetPeople();

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, people);

            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var text = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image: Resulting XML]

So the DataContractSerializer is able to deal with properties with a private setter, whilst the XmlSerializer isn't.

Comment: Would be great if you have some deeplinks to the code (as everything is open source these days)

Comment: @Pieterjan In case of DTOs, even i dont specify any datacontracts, serialisation is successful. This makes think. Well if u can redirect to a documentation or a code sample. I ll appreciate more.